# How Can I solve this Pubspec.yaml problem

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, pubspec

How Can I solve this in Pubspec.yaml Code problem

when pub get it show:

```
C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub upgrade
Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.13.4.

Because test >=1.16.0-nullsafety <1.16.0-nullsafety.8 requires SDK version >=2.10.0-0 <2.12.0 and test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.8 <1.16.0-nullsafety.18 depends on typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0, test >=1.16.0-nullsafety <1.16.0-nullsafety.18 requires typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0.
And because test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.18 <1.16.0-nullsafety.19 depends on test_api 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 and test >=1.3.0 <1.12.0 depends on boolean_selector ^1.0.0, test >=1.3.0 <1.12.0-∞ or >=1.16.0-nullsafety <1.16.0-nullsafety.19 requires typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0 or test_api 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 or boolean_selector ^1.0.0.
And because test >=1.12.0 <1.13.0 depends on test_api 0.2.14 and test >=1.13.0 <1.14.5 depends on test_api 0.2.15, test >=1.3.0 <1.14.5-∞ or >=1.16.0-nullsafety <1.16.0-nullsafety.19 requires typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0 or test_api 0.2.14 or 0.2.15 or 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 or boolean_selector ^1.0.0.
And because test >=1.14.5 <1.15.0 depends on test_api 0.2.16 and test >=1.15.0 <1.15.3 depends on test_api 0.2.17, test >=1.3.0 <1.15.3-∞ or >=1.16.0-nullsafety <1.16.0-nullsafety.19 requires typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0 or test_api 0.2.14 or 0.2.15 or 0.2.16 or 0.2.17 or 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 or boolean_selector ^1.0.0.
And because test >=1.15.3 <1.15.5 depends on test_api 0.2.18 and test >=1.15.5 <1.16.0-nullsafety depends on test_api 0.2.18+1, test >=1.3.0 <1.16.0-nullsafety.19 requires typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0 or test_api 0.2.14 or 0.2.15 or 0.2.16 or 0.2.17 or 0.2.18 or 0.2.18+1 or 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 or boolean_selector ^1.0.0.
And because test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.19 <1.16.6 depends on test_api 0.2.19 and every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on boolean_selector 2.1.0, if test >=1.3.0 <1.16.6 and flutter_test any from sdk then test_api 0.2.14 or 0.2.15 or 0.2.16 or 0.2.17 or 0.2.18 or 0.2.18+1 or 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 or 0.2.19 or typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0.
And because every version of flutter from sdk depends on typed_data 1.3.0 and every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on test_api 0.3.0, one of flutter any from sdk or test >=1.3.0 <1.16.6 or flutter_test any from sdk must be false.
And because mercadopago_sdk <1.3.0 depends on test ^1.5.1+1 and test >=1.16.6 depends on shelf_static ^1.0.0, if flutter any from sdk and flutter_test any from sdk and mercadopago_sdk <1.3.0 then shelf_static ^1.0.0.
And because shelf_static >=1.0.0 depends on mime ^1.0.0 and share >=0.6.5 <2.0.0-nullsafety.2 depends on mime ^0.9.7, one of flutter any from sdk or flutter_test any from sdk or mercadopago_sdk <1.3.0 or share >=0.6.5 <2.0.0-nullsafety.2 must be false.
And because fooddelivery depends on both share 0.6.5+3 and mercadopago_sdk 1.2.0, flutter from sdk is incompatible with flutter_test from sdk.
So, because fooddelivery depends on both flutter any from sdk and flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the top of your main.dart

```
// @dart=2.9
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that their versions are incompatible with each other. Take a look, and leave them standardized and with the same versions

Comment: send your pubspec.yaml for we analysis your problem